# What happened to the Spring Modules project?

Tags: java, spring, lucene

I read on Spring web site that the Spring Modules project is now deprecated in favor of Spring Extensions. However, unless I am missing something, Spring Extensions does not support Lucene like Spring Modules did.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think you're missing anything. Users of Spring Modules were rather left in the lurch, I feel.

There is an alternative to Spring Lucene, though, which is [Compass](http://compass-project.org/). Rather than being a library to make lucene easier, it actually provides an abstraction layer on top of Lucene. I like it, I;ve used it for several lucene-based projects now, it's good quality.

Comment: +1 for Compass - unfortunately it is a one man show with no new releases in the past 12 month though

Comment: @sfussenegger: Yes, that is starting to worry me a bit.